# Area of a triangle which is part of a square

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, area

> Each side of square $\text{ABCD}$ is $2$ units in length. $P$ is a point on $\text{BD}$ such that $\angle BCP=30°$. Area of $\triangle DCP$ can be expressed as $a-\sqrt{a}$. Then, $a=?$

Source: [Junior category, Dhaka Regional 2017, Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad (BdMO)](http://www.matholympiad.org.bd/)

Possibly this requires the use of Pythagorean Theorem and the basic trig functions, since right-angle triangles are possibly also involved. I understand the question, but I don't see where to start in the figure I end up with. Maybe I'm having trouble drawing the figure correctly — I was taught at school to name the points of a 2d shape either clockwise or anti-clockwise.

[image]

Comment: Area of $\triangle DCP = \frac{bh}{2}=a-\sqrt{a}$, try to find the base and height. Also, try to find $\frac{h}{b}$ (using trig. )

Comment: If you think a good guess would be close nough: The area of the square is $4$, area of $BCD$ is $2$, area of $DCP$ is (very roughly) $\frac23$ of that, so should be about $\frac43$. Now try $a=1,2,3,4,\ldots$ and see what might fit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the law of sines in triangle $DCP$,
$$\frac{DP}{CP}=\frac{\sin(60^\circ)}{\sin(45^\circ)}$$
and by the law of sines in triangle $BCP$,
$$\frac{BP}{CP}=\frac{\sin(30^\circ)}{\sin(45^\circ)}$$
hence
$$\frac{DP}{BP}=\frac{\sin(60^\circ)}{\sin(30^\circ)}=\sqrt{3}$$
so
$$DP =BP(\sqrt{3})$$
Then
$$2\sqrt{2} = DB = DP + BP = BP(\sqrt{3})+BP = BP(\sqrt{3} + 1)$$
hence
$$
BP
= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3} + 1}
=\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}
$$
so
\begin{align*}
\text{area}(\Delta{BCP})
&=\frac{1}{2}(BC)(BP)\sin(45^\circ)\\[4pt]
&=
\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)
(2)
(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})
\left({\small{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}}\right)
\\[4pt]
&=\sqrt{3}-1\\[10pt]
&
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!
\text{Hence:}&\\[4pt]
\text{area}(\Delta{DCP})
&=\text{area}(\Delta{BCD})-\text{area}(\Delta{BCP})\\[4pt]
&=2-(\sqrt{3}-1)\\[4pt]
&=3-\sqrt{3}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $\triangle DCP$ and apply sine formula to find $PD$. The area is $\frac{1}{2}(2)(PD)\sin45^\circ$.

You may need $\sin75^\circ=\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Extend $CP$. Let's say this line will intersect $AB$ at point $O$. $BO=0.5 \cdot CO, \: CO=2\cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}, BO=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ (30/60/90 triangle). Now it's easy to see that $\triangle{DPC}$ is similar to $\triangle{POB}$ and from here we can obtain that $DP=\sqrt{3}\cdot PB, \:CP=\sqrt{3}\cdot PO$. Hope you can finish it now.

Comment: How can you tell that BO is half of CO? Is it just a guess or a well-founded assumption?

Answer (score 0):

$$S_{\Delta DCP}=\frac{2^2\sin45^{\circ}\sin60^{\circ}}{2\sin75^{\circ}}=\frac{4\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}{2}}{2\cdot\frac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2}}=\frac{2\sqrt3}{\sqrt3+1}=\sqrt3(\sqrt3-1)=3-\sqrt3.$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

\begin{align} 
[CPD]&=[CQD]+[CPQ]=1+\tfrac12\cdot\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt2\cdot\tan15^\circ=1+\tan15^\circ
,\\
\tan15^\circ&=
\frac{\sin15^\circ}{\cos15^\circ}
=
\frac{2\sin15^\circ\cos 15^\circ}{2\cos^2 15^\circ-1+1}
=
\frac{\sin30^\circ}{\cos30^\circ+1}
\\
&=
\frac{\tfrac12}{\tfrac{\sqrt3}2+1}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt3+2}
=\frac{\sqrt3-2}{3-4}=2-\sqrt3
,\\
[CPD]&=1+2-\sqrt3=3-\sqrt3=a-\sqrt{a}
,
\end{align}

hence $a=3$.